# Dynamic Desktop wallpaper thumbnails

Tags: macos, wallpaper, system-settings

I have downloaded various "Dynamic Desktop" wallpapers online, put them into a directory, and added this directory to my **Desktop & Screen Saver** preference pane.

The problem is, it does not correctly the thumbnails. They all appear to be the "Mojave" wallpaper, while in reality they each are different pictures.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

On Mojave the system doesn't generate correct thumbnails. The only workaround is to place the wallpaper into `/Library/Desktop Pictures/` and place its thumbnail into `/Library/Desktop Pictures/.thumbnails/` folder. This requires administrator password and can only be performed from terminal.

```
sudo cp mywallpaper.heic /Library/Desktop\ Pictures/
sudo cp mywallpaper_thumbnail.heic /Library/Desktop\ Pictures/.thumbnails/mywallpaper.heic
```

Thumbnail has to have same name as wallpaper. macOS Catalina can create correct thumbnail. Custom thumbnails are only supported for wallpapers inside `Desktop Pictures` folder.

[image: Wallpaper thumbnails]